# What is faster Renaming files, Changing an attribute in them or Moving them between folders

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I'm developing a file system manager module, and wondering what will be a more efficient approach.

This will be on a Windows machine with NTFS.

The module will need to notify a different module regarding new files created on a specific directory and also maintain some kind of state for this files so already processed files can be deleted, and in case of failure, the unprocessed files will be processed again.

I thought of either moving files between directories as their state changes, or renaming files according to their state or changing the files attributes as a sign of their state.

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient approach, considering the possibility of a large quantity of files being created over a short time span.

Answer (score 3):

I can't fully answer your question, but give some general hints. Most important of all, the answer to your question might largely depend on the underlying file system (NTFS, FAT32, etc.).

Renaming or moving a file on the same partition generally means that directory entries are changed. The actual file contents need not be touched. Once you move a file to a different partition or hard disk drive, the actual file contents must be copied, too, which takes far more time.

That all being said, I would generally assume a rename to be *slightly* quicker than moving a file to another directory (on the same partition), since only one directory is affected instead of two. I'm also not quite sure what you mean by changing a file "attribute" -- however, if you're talking about e.g. setting the "archive" flag of a file, or making the file "read-only", that might again be *slightly* faster than a rename, if the directory entry can be changed in-place instead of being replaced with a new one of a different size.

Again: Do take my assumptions with caution, since this all depends on the particular file system. (For example, hiding a file on a UNIX file system usually means renaming it -- prefixing the name with a `.` --, but the same is not true for typical DOS/Windows file systems.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. this will be on a windows machine with NTFS formatted drive. the file "attribute" i was referring to is something like setting the Archive flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
Renaming took: 1498.8166
ApplyAttribute took: 340.5407
Transfer took: 2527.6837
Transfer took: 3933.4944
ApplyAttribute took: 419.635
Renaming took: 1384.0079
```

Tested with 1000 files.
Run tests twice in order to ensure no caching is in place.

EDITED: nasty bug was fixed, sorry.

Go with attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store this information directly in the filesystem? I would recommend using a SQL database to keep track of the files. That way, you avoid modifying the filesystem, it's probably going to be faster, and you can easily have more information about the files if you need them.

Also, having one folder with large amount of files might be slow by itself, so you might consider having more folders for the files, if that makes sense for you.